# Why does WP_Query show only the same post even with different categories and endwhile?

Tags: php, posts, wp-query

I have 3 divs that WP_Query with 3 different categories and end it with the php endwhile,but it only shows the same most recent post query three times over. Do I need to hard reset the query loop somehow? I'm looking to see where to put wp_reset_postdata...

```
<div>
    <?php $test = new WP_Query('category=[errands]&showposts=1');
    while ($test->have_posts()) : $test->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/errands.jpg" />

        <?php the_content(__('Read more'));?>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>

 <div>
    <?php $test2 = new WP_Query('category=[shopping]&showposts=1');
    while ($test2->have_posts()) : $test2->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/shopping.jpg" />

        <?php the_content(__('Read more'));?>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>

 <div>
    <?php $test3 = new WP_Query('category=[calendar_maintenance]&showposts=1');
    while ($test3->have_posts()) : $test3->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/calendar.jpg" />

        <?php the_content(__('Read more'));?>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you try `wp_reset_postdata()` (see Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)) ? ps: `posts_per_page`  is the new `showposts`.

Comment: No I was using the wp_reset_query. I will try <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> now. And see if it works.

Comment: The categories are the tax slugs so i will look into query_var true do wp_reset_postdata only once

Comment: @G.M. when I use 'cat=1' instead of category=[errands] the post doesn't even show. Is there something wrong with my category

Comment: I'm lost: you are using categories or custom taxonomies? They are **not** same thing.

Comment: @G.M. I am using categories.

Comment: See @user48752 answer, use `'category_name=errands'`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your posts based on different categories you should use `category_name` or `cat` as category id. For example;

```
<?php $test = new WP_Query('cat=1&showposts=1'); // where 1 is the id of your cat ?>
```

Or

```
 <?php $test = new WP_Query('category_name=errands&showposts=1'); ?>
```

Also, you need to call `wp_reset_postdata();` after each `WP_Query`. I hope this helps

More on how to use categories in `WP_Query`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Undeletung since per discussion custom taxonomies are not relevant.